# conditional var count with different classes in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
class    ID  rank
a        AA  win
b        AA  win
b        AB  win
c        BB  win
d        AB  win
e        BB  win
e        AA  win
```

How can I most efficiently count how much `wins` per `ID` I have with a condition of class lower than `e` (not inclusive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(class !="e") %>%summarize(n())
```

Comment: Sure! dplyr has the pipe operator `%>%`. It can be interpreted as "and then". So read the code as follows. Take your df, and then group by an id variable, and then filter the rows of the df that are not belonging to the "e" class, and then summarize by the count in each group.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one:

```
aggregate(rank~ID, df[as.character(df$class)<"e",], length)

# ID rank
#1 AA    2
#2 AB    2
#3 BB    1
```

As for what @Richard Scriven pointed out in the comments (thanks for that):

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use

If we run `Sys.getlocale()`, we would get:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United 
    States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United
    States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

We can set the locale with:

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") #LC_TIME for example
```

See `?locales` for more info.

Comment: This is exactly what I had thought of as well.  OP just beware of lexicographic order with respect to locale, as mentioned in `help("<")`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'ID', specify the `i` with the logical expression (`class != "e"`) and get the number of rows (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[class != "e",.(N = .N), by = ID]
#   ID N
#1: AA 2
#2: AB 2
#3: BB 1
```